# How can I obtain the Worldsheet current superpartner under ${\cal N}=1$ SUSY?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, fermions, supersymmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I want to derive the energy-momentum stress tensor $T_{ab}$ from the ${\cal N}=1$ SUSY transformation,
$$
\delta_\epsilon X^\mu = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha'}{2}} \bar{\epsilon} \psi^\mu
$$
$$
\delta_\epsilon \psi^\mu = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha'}} \rho^\alpha \partial_\alpha X^\mu \epsilon
$$
on the Worldsheet current

$$
G_a = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2\alpha'}} \rho^b \rho_a \psi^\mu \partial_b X_\mu
$$
resorting to the Fierz rearrangement formula for spinors in $D=2$
$$
(\bar{\lambda}\psi)\chi_\alpha = -\frac{1}{2} \left[ (\bar{\lambda}\chi)\psi_\alpha + (\bar{\lambda} \bar{\rho} \chi)(\bar{\rho}\psi)_\alpha + (\bar{\lambda} \rho^\alpha \chi)(\rho_\alpha \psi)_\alpha \right]
$$

But I'm having a hard time understanding where to apply this rearrangement formula. Appreciate any help.